# why twig put auto space on for loop

Tags: for-loop, twig, space

this is a simple twig for loop

```twig
{% for number in numberlist %}
    {{number}}
    {% if loop.last == false %}, {% else %}.{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

why the result is :

120 ,   121 ,   122 ,   123 ,   124 ,   125 ,   126 ,   127 ,   128 ,   129 ,   130 ,   131 ,   132 ,   133 .

with a space after each number

Thanks

Comment: What is the result you are expecting ? You added a white space after your comma in your condition, so that is why your include has one.

Comment: Anyway, you're better off using  [`join`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/join.html) filter. Something like `{{ numberlist|join(',') }}.`

Comment: If you don't want `twig` considering spaces you'd need to use the tag [`{% spaceless %}`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/spaceless.html)

Comment: this is was i expected
120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133.
with a space after the ',' and in last a point '.' without space after it

Comment: spaceless doesn't work it s the same result

Comment: Yeah, only works betweens HTML tags it seems. Anyway the `newlines` are "messing" up your expected output. Putting it all on one line helps, see [here](https://twigfiddle.com/e689h8). If you want "proper" html, you could use `ob_start('ob_tidyhandler');`

Answer (score 0):

It works if I delete all spaces in my HTML, like this:

```twig
{% for number in numberlist %}{{number}}{% if loop.last == false %}, {% else %}.{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

It's a little ugly, but it works.

Comment: As pointed out in my other comment, you can use the [`join`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/join.html) filter to rewrite this expression in a simpler way if you want: `{{ numberlist|join(', ') }}.`. With this approach, no worries about whitespaces ;)

Comment: Yes, that is why I added a point after the twig expression. As you can see with this [twig fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/9kspug) both your expression and mine, using `join` filter produce the same output.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to trim leading or trailing whitespace by using special modifier:

```twig
{% for number in numberlist %}
    {{- number- }}
    {{- loop.last ? ', ' : '.' }}
{% endfor %}
```

There is a [whitespace control topic](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#templates-whitespace-control) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have spaces in front of the comma, you can also add '`-`' in **for** loop

You can do like this:

```
{%- for number in numberlist -%}
    {{- number -}}
    {% if loop.last == false %}, {% else %}.{% endif %}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Result:
`120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133.`